# Is my network affected by malware?

Tags: wifi, virus-removal

I am using Wi-Fi at my home, so I can connect more devices like my phone and computer in the same network. For the past two months, whatever website I visit, it loads for a long time and at the end it is redirecting to xtaff.com, tradeexchange.com, etc some other websites, ads are opening. I could not got to any website. But some standard ecommerce websites, Stack Exchange websites are loading fine but with low speed.

I could not find why it is happening like this. If I used my mobile with my same network, it is also facing same problem, and sometime I am getting the message like '**Your phone is affected by virus**', then it stops there.

But If I use my mobile or computer at my office i.e connecting to some other network, I can get the same websites with fine loading including good speed.

What is the problem with the wi-fi? How can find it and remove it? I am using free antivirus software only (Avast).

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I am using the windows7

Answer (score 8):

Since according to your description all systems in your network are affected and independent from the operating system, the chances are high that your router is compromised and the DNS settings are changed. This way most outgoing traffic can be controlled by the attacker which leads to all these redirects to ads. This type of compromise is not uncommon as you can see [from a google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=router+compromised+ads).

What you need to do first is fix your router, that is make a firmware reset and update it to the latest firmware. If the router is out of support, if the model is known to be insecure or if the vendor is known to be unable to make secure devices (this includes most vendors of cheap devices) throw it away and get a better router. For more information see [routersecurity.org](http://routersecurity.org/).

After you've fixed your router you should also make sure that all your systems are clean since compromised routers are not only used to deliver ads but also malware.

Comment: Is there any tool to update the firmware?

Comment: @SIBHIS: The firmware itself and the way the router gets updated are specific to the router model, i.e. there is no single software to deal with all routers. Some routers can search for new firmware from the administration interface, for others you have to look at the support web pages of the vendor.

Comment: If no firmware update is available, you may be able to install a third-party firmware such as OpenWRT.